# Final Cut pro X cropped output media

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, output

I've created simple 7 seconds clop which uses standard plugin for FCPX: "Bold Fin" title.
While i am editing this clip - everything fits to the screen:
[image: FCPX during edit]

but when actual file is ready - it seems like it is cropped:
[image: Quick time player replays master file]

Could somebody please help to find a reason why my output actually cropped? And how fix this issue?

Comment: Can you detail the export preset you're using?

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like the whole frame is cropped to me. It looks like the animated part has been scaled. I still see the black bar at the bottom in the exported version. Is it possible the animation is in something like a compound clip and the compound clip has some scaling applied?

Comment: No, I am not using any compound clips: 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ7DH.png

Comment: And here is my sharing settings: [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wIkjV.png)